# Why am I getting virus alert after clean formatting MacBook Pro 2014?

Tags: macbook-pro, anti-virus

I recently clean formatted, erased everything on the hard drive of, my MacBook Pro 2014 and installed OS X El Capitan.

I also installed Sophos Aniti-Virus, but Sophos is detecting Android Apperhand virus in my clean installed Mac.

The alert is showing everytime my MacBook Pro logs in. Later it vanished from the Sophos Quarantine Manager!

I have attached the snapshot below.
[image]

Comment: If you open the quarantine manager does is show that you downloaded it from iCloud or in a mail attachment? I wouldn't expect an android program run, but it would be good to know from whence it came.

Comment: @bmike I dont know, but it shows everytime I login to my macbook and vanishes automatically in a few seconds

Answer (score 1):

The virus was in a folder in googledrive.

So after formatting and not installing google drive the virus warning doesnt show.

I deleted the folder from google drive so it no longer shows the virus even after installing google drive